# How to extract data from json object in wordpress using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress

I have json object which have the results but the problem is that i am not been able to load the data into the div this is my json

```
{
  "userScreen": "rashisalabo",
  "userName": "\u53e4\u5ddd\u7d75\u7f8e",
  "tweetCreated": "2019-05-22 11:26:13",
  "tweetText": "\u7c73\u4eba\u6750\u7cfb\u60c5\u5831\u30b5\u30a4\u30c8\u304c\u3001\u3055\u307e\u3056\u307e\u306a\u8077\u696d\u306e\u53ce\u5165\u3084\u52b4\u50cd\u74b0\u5883\u3001\u30b9\u30c8\u30ec\u30b9\u3001\u6210\u9577\u6027\u306a\u3069\u3092\u30b9\u30b3\u30a2\u5316\u3057\u3066\u30e9\u30f3\u30ad\u30f3\u30b0\u5316\u3057\u305f\u300cThe 2018 Jobs Rated Report\u300d\u3067\u3001\u30e9\u30f3\u30ad\u30f3\u30b0\u30c8\u30c3\u30d7\u306f\u907a\u4f1d\u30ab\u30a6\u30f3\u30bb\u30e9\u30fc\u3067\u30012\u4f4d\u6570\u5b66\u8005\u30013\u4f4d\u5927\u5b66\u6559\u6388\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/AS7cTUspbE",
  "tweetRetweetCt": "0",
  "tweetFavoriteCt": "0"
}
```

**and this is the code in which i have tried to convert the json and load into the div .**

```
 $.post(c, {page:p, action: "my_loadmore"}, function(data) {

  console.log(data.userScreen);

$("#left-area").append('<article id="mypost" class="et_pb_post post-29 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized"><div class="TweetMasonry__topbar"><a href="http://jobplace360.com/2019/04/26/abc/" class="topbarName">'+ data +'</a></div></article>');

});
   }
```

Comment: You can't just stick a raw object of key value pairs into html and expect it to generate html.  `"stuff"+ data +"other stuff"` is going to result in the object calling `toString()` on itself.  Depending on the implementation, that could be anything, included the infamous `[object Object]`

Comment: @taplar can you make an example in the answer

Comment: I don't know how you are wanting to display that object in your link.

Comment: i just want to show in the console

Comment: Showing in the console would be `console.log(data)` and wouldn't have anything to do with appending it to html.

Comment: thats i am doing I want to show the userScreen value in the console.log()

Comment: You're already doing that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194963/discussion-between-tayyab-gulsher-vohra-and-taplar).